# PHP sockets problem

Tags: php, sockets

Hey guys, I am trying to do some socket programming in PHP.

So I am running a socket "server":

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9999';

$masterSocket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($masterSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($masterSocket, $address, $port);
socket_listen($masterSocket, 5);
$clientSocket = socket_accept($masterSocket);
```

So I open up SSH and run this script. It is running, no errors.

Then I have another PHP script which attempts to connect to this:

```
$fp = fsockopen("me.com", 9999, $errno, $errstr, 30);

fclose($fp);
```

but it's giving me:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to me.com:9999 (Connection refused)
```

How do I begin to fix this?

Comment: Why would you connect to: `me.com:9999` ?

Comment: it looks like you are binding to one IP and connection to another with this code, however you mentioned in comments you were connecting to 127.0.0.1, can you update the question to reflect so we can see everything in 1 place

Answer (score 0):

You haven't finished the listening socket sequence, you need to call `socket_accept` to accept new connections.  There is an example in the comments in the PHP documentation.

```
$clients = array();
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket,'127.0.0.1',$port);
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while(true)
{
    if(($newc = socket_accept($socket)) !== false)
    {
        echo "Client $newc has connected\n";
        $clients[] = $newc;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php

Comment: Hi Sorry, I didn't paste all my code. I actually do have the socket_accept() call. I copied and pasted ur code and tried to run it and I get the error: Warning: socket_accept(): unable to accept incoming connection [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable in /home/sbirds/public_html/socketserver.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if the port is firewalled off. You could use telnet to check this.

2) See if it works when the client and server are on the same machine (I'm guessing from your mention of SSH that the server is remote).

3) If it works locally and you can hit the remote port using other tools then it's going to be tricky. I'd suggest you wail and gnash your teeth for a bit; I'm out of ideas.

EDIT: Heh. Or you could just read Steve-o's answer. Teeth-gnashing is still an option.

Comment: It might be the firewall. How do I check this?

Comment: If you can telnet to that port then you'll know it's not the firewall. If you have control of the server then you can manually check the configuration.

Comment: By the way, if you *cannot* telnet to that port that doesn't necessarily mean it's the firewall to blame...you can rule out the firewall with telnet but it will take more digging to conclusively prove that it's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, can't telnet to the port either.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that "me.com" is an example but, just to be sure, socket_bind is expecting an IP address.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php :

> **address**
>
> If the socket is of the
>   AF_INET family, the address is an IP
>   in dotted-quad notation (e.g.
>   127.0.0.1).
>
> If the socket is of the AF_UNIX
>   family, the address is the path of a
>   Unix-domain socket (e.g.
>   /tmp/my.sock).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is very old, but if someone still has this problem, make sure you connect to the *SAME* address you are listening on,

For example, If you're listening on `127.0.0.1` and your Machine address is `me.com`, you won't be able to connect to `me.com` with it, for that you'll have to listen on `me.com`.

```
Listening on: localhost:8088
Can only connect via: localhost:8088 // not via me.com:8088

Listening on: me.com:8088
Can only connect via: me.com:8088 // not via localhost:8088
```